# Xamarin Forms Round Button

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm using Xamarin Forms 4.1.0.581479 and the same version of Xamarin Forms Visual Material.

I've made a round button that I'm using as a close button for a couple of modal overlays. It looks like this:

[image]

The problem is that I can't make the x in the middle (from the Material icon font) larger. Currently it has a font size of 20

As soon as I start to increase the font size, e.g. to 30, this starts to happen:

[image]

I've tried setting the Padding of the button to zero, I've tried playing with the HorizontalOption, I've tried setting BorderWidth to 0, but nothing seems to make any difference.

How do I increase the font-size without clipping the icon?

As requested, here is my XAML:

```
<Button Grid.Column="1" Text="{x:Static constants:IconFont.Close}" Clicked="OnClicked" Style="{StaticResource CloseButton}" />
```

The `CloseButton` style is as follows:

```xml
    <Style x:Key="CloseButton" TargetType="Button">
      <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource MaterialFontFamily}" />
      <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#0075BE" />
      <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20" />
      <Setter Property="WidthRequest" Value="50" />
      <Setter Property="HeightRequest" Value="50" />
      <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="End" />
      <Setter Property="BorderRadius" Value="25" />
    </Style>
```

Comment: Post your Xaml, so that we can see as well.

Comment: are you changing `WidthRequest` and `HeightRequest` when you change fontsize to 30? If yes , how and where?Please show . And what is `MaterialFontFamily` set to?

Comment: Thanks Prateek, No I wasn't changing the width/height because I don't want the overall button to get any bigger, just the text. Have fixed it now though :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should use ImageButton instead of Button:

```
<ImageButton VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" BackgroundColor="AliceBlue" CornerRadius="25" WidthRequest="50" HeightRequest="50">
                <ImageButton.Source>
                    <FontImageSource
                FontFamily="{DynamicResource MaterialFontFamily}"
                Glyph="{DynamicResource IconClose}"
                Size="30"
                Color="Red" />
                </ImageButton.Source>
</ImageButton>
```